# Text-indent refuses to work on a paragraph

Tags: html, css, text

No need explanation. Just text-indent doesn't function properly. Somewhere i read that the element must be with `display: inline-block` but the paragraph is a block element so no reason not to work. Can you chech my code to see where I am wrong ? http://jsfiddle.net/x0e86ewb/

Comment: If you want to only indent the first line it works by default [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x0e86ewb/2/) here i've just removed the `:first-line` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added it on your code in jsfiddle and works well in the first line of all paragraphs.

```
p {
    text-indent:90px;
}
```

If you need move all the paragraph my conseil is use another property. 
margin or padding depends of your needs.